# show graph from plunker on webpage

Tags: d3.js, plunker

I am using [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) to create an interactive bar graph. I coded the graph just fine but I cannot figure out how to download the graph onto the webpage I would like to put it on.
[Here's the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gZbl2NkPsVxGSp4qVCAe?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: #C50707
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: #FF7171;
}

.title {
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(20, 260);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", x(data[0].name))
      .attr("y", -26)
      .text("Office Supply Stores in Pennsylvania 2010-2015");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by webpage ?

Comment: I was trying to make a chart to put on my work's website. I made the chart without any problems but now I am confused as to what to do next.

Comment: Just added an answer below, read and mark as answer if it helps. Feel free to ask if you're still having some issue by mentioning exact problem.

On the other hand, this is just a basic thing, I'll prefer to take some short courses or tutorials over internet for better understanding. Do ask exact questions here in future keeping in mind the [question asking guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to copy the mentioned code to your project, then this is really simple. See the [updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZFI2VmAmXcVRhCi0M4Xs?p=preview) where I've added the entire javascript and styling to separate files named style.css and script.js. All you have to do is copy these files or content of these files to your project files. Must include these files in your html file as I did.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Html body here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(20, 260);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", x(data[0].name))
      .attr("y", -26)
      .text("Office Supply Stores in Pennsylvania 2010-2015");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

**style.css**

```
.bar {
  fill: #C50707
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: #FF7171;
}

.title {
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```